# How to modify .bash_login remotely?

Tags: linux

I did something stupid which was adding the command exit 0 to .bash_login.

Now i'm stuck since whenever i try logging in, it just exits automatically.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? I'm currently using a windows PC to ssh to a linux plug computer.

Comment: should be moved to [Super User](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ssh user@host "/bin/bash --noprofile"
```

See manpages for `ssh` and `bash` to see how this works. May need some modifications-- for example, if bash isn't in /bin on the remote machine. You will need a command-line ssh client, but I believe one is available for Cygwin on Windows.

After that, you should have a usable shell so you can fix your .bash_login.

Comment: I am using putty to connect to the plug computer, so access is only via ssh. How can I do this if i cannot log in.

Comment: I'm telling you to find a command-line SSH client for Windows and log in using that instead of putty. If you call SSH from the command line, you can optionally specify a command to run on the remote machine _instead_ of the default login shell. The command which will be run on the remote machine is `/bin/bash --noprofile`, which tells Bash not to run your .bash_login.

Comment: used winscp and modified the file. thanks!

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Can you start a different shell?

```
ssh user@host tcsh
```

Then, in the different shell, fix or rename the file.